# After switching WebDriver to alert Marionette stops working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, marionette

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
public void deleteOffer(){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/main/div/div/div/div[2]/a[2]")).click();
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div")).click();
    }
```

Im getting this error: `1494803297020   Marionette  INFO    New connections will no longer be accepted`

It seems like it's stopping working right after `driver.switchTo().alert().accept();` so I guess the reason is that I shoul switch back to main frame but I don't know how to do it. I have tried `driver.switchTo().parentFrame();` and `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` but getting still the same error.

Comment: try doing this in following manner:  `Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert(); alert.accept();` see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to your Question:

I don't see any error as such in your code, but I will suggest the following:

1. Before you switch to `Alert` to Accept, slow down a bit, induce some `wait`.
2. If you are using `driver.switchTo().alert().accept()` then you don't need to switch back to the main frame.
3. When you are trying to find out some element on the main page by `driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div")).click();`,slow down a bit, induce some `wait` again.
4. The error you see `New connections will no longer be accepted` is something serious `Marionette` complaining about which essentially means you are trying a test step which can't be achieved by the geckodriver. Hence you may need to change your code for the geckodriver to proceed with the task.
5. Finally, both of your xpath looks petty vulnerable to me. Instead of using absolute xpath you should try to use logical unique xpath.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thanks, I added wait and noticed that path wasn't right at all. Now it's working fine :)

Comment: @Aloha Please upvote the Answer as well if it was useful to you :) Thanks